# React-js Fetch api being called multiple times during Login

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to the React world, and usage of components, I have an underlying issue where I have a Login Component that I call from `App.js` render().

The `Login.js` is having a `fetch()` api, which is used to fetch the response of whatever is typed on the `form`.

**Expected Result** - One time call to the `fetch` api, when I click the `submit` button within the form and then Login.

**Actual Result** - `fetch` api is getting called multiple times, when I am filling the form, rite from the point I start typing on the form, The complete result succeeds after I complete typing the `username` and `password` and the `submit` button does not seem to have any affect as such.

Relevant Code About what I am taking about above :

The `useform.js` that you see below is the hooks that I am using.

`App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Header from './components/Header.js'
import Login from './components/Login.js'

class App extends Component {
  render() {                                                                                                                                                             
      return (
      <div className="container">
       <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`Login.js`

```
import React  from "react"
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import useForm from './useForm.js'
// Using hooks instead of a Class and constructor


const Login = () => {
    const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm(signup)

    function signup(){
        console.log(values)
    }

    var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
        targetUrl = '...'

    fetch ( proxyUrl+targetUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
            },
        body: JSON.stringify(values)
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((values) => {
        console.log('Success:', values)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error)
    })


    return (
<Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Row>
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridUserName">
            <Form.Label>UserName</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
                autoFocus
                name={'username'}
                value={values.username}
                type='username'
                placeholder="username"
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridFirstName">
            <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
            autoFocus
            name={'firstname'}
            value={values.firstname}
            type='first name'
            placeholder="First name"
            onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridSecondName">
            <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
            autoFocus
            name={'lastname'}
            value={values.lastname}
            type='last name'
            placeholder="Last name"
            onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </Form.Group>
    </Form.Row>

    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
        autoFocus
        type="email"
        name={'email'}
        value={values.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter email"
        />
        <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>

  <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
        autoFocus
        type="password"
        name={'password'}
        value={values.password}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Password" />
    </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
            <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
    </Form.Group>

    <Button
        variant="primary"
        type="submit"
        value="Submit"
        >
        Login
    </Button>

</Form>
  );
}

export default Login
```

How do I run the react app, is as simple as `npm start` from within the `src` folder, my folder structure if you are curious about some particular file, that you would want to look at

```
planner-app/
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
└── src

planner-app/src
├── App.css
├── App.js
├── components
│   ├── Header.js
│   ├── Login.css
│   ├── Login.js
│   ├── MainComponent.js
│   └── useForm.js
├── index.css
├── index.js
├── logo.svg
├── serviceWorker.js
└── setupTests.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your login/fetch logic only after you've submitted the form.

In this case, put your fetch logic in `handleSubmit`. That way, it is only called once the form submits (`onSubmit`).

Answer (score 0):

So a react component will run all of the code before the return statement every time the component rerenders, when you are filling in the form, the component is rerendering and therefore recalling the fetch api. To stop this, put the api code within a function that is only called when you submit the form.

```
const submitForm = () => {
// call api here

}
```